# Getting syntax error while using group by in update statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

Getting syntax error while using group by in update statement in SQL Server

```
    Update LegMove

        set   Event_Code =  max(case when m.Status_Description = 'DPKL' then l.Status_Description else NULL end),                                                  
              Create_Date = max(case when m.Status_Description = 'DPKL' then dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,l.Move_Create_Timestamp),0) else NULL end), 
              PTimeStamp=max(case when m.Status_Description = 'DPKL' then l.Move_Create_Timestamp else NULL end), 
              Acrual_Date=max(case when m.Status_Description = 'DPKL' then dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,l.Move_Status_Timestamp),0) else NULL end) 
FROM wrkLegMove m 
inner join MovementMaster l with(nolock) on l.Leg_Key = m.Leg_Key and l.Status_Description = m.Status_Description and l.Move_Create_Timestamp = m. FirstMoveTime 
where m.Status_Description in ('DPKL') 
group by m.Leg_Key, l.Shipment_Number, l.Shipment_Leg_Sequence
```

Comment: Well if you have an error you should also post the error.

Comment: m. FirstMoveTime should be m.FirstMoveTime?

Comment: Getting error because of aggregate values , i know update statement cant use group by , am looking for alternative query

Comment: why don't you create inner query for your MovementMaster table, then go ahead with the update process. You may use 'CTE' to create your sub query.

Answer (score 0):

Try below - it seems that you don't need any group by

```
Update m1 set   
              Event_Code =  max(case when m.Status_Description = 'DPKL' then l.Status_Description else NULL end),                                                  
              Create_Date = max(case when m.Status_Description = 'DPKL' then dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,l.Move_Create_Timestamp),0) else NULL end), 
              PTimeStamp=max(case when m.Status_Description = 'DPKL' then l.Move_Create_Timestamp else NULL end), 
              Acrual_Date=max(case when m.Status_Description = 'DPKL' then dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,l.Move_Status_Timestamp),0) else NULL end) 
FROM LegMove m1 inner join wrkLegMove m on m.leg_key=m1.leg_key
inner join MovementMaster l with(nolock) on l.Leg_Key = m.Leg_Key and l.Status_Description = m.Status_Description and l.Move_Create_Timestamp = m. FirstMoveTime 
where m.Status_Description in ('DPKL')
```

Comment: UPDATE table is different and FROM table is different

Comment: @Tulsi, what is the relation key between your update table and form table

Answer (score 0):

you could use a subselect

```
update lm set Event_Code = mx.Event_Code, 
    Create_Date = mx.Create_Date, 
    PTimeStamp = mx.PTimeStamp, 
    Acrual_Date = mx.Acrual_Date
from LegMove lm
    inner join (
    select m.leg_key,
        Event_Code =  max(case when m.Status_Description = 'DPKL' then l.Status_Description else NULL end),                                                  
        Create_Date = max(case when m.Status_Description = 'DPKL' then dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,l.Move_Create_Timestamp),0) else NULL end), 
        PTimeStamp=max(case when m.Status_Description = 'DPKL' then l.Move_Create_Timestamp else NULL end), 
        Acrual_Date=max(case when m.Status_Description = 'DPKL' then dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,l.Move_Status_Timestamp),0) else NULL end) 
    FROM wrkLegMove m 
        inner join MovementMaster l with(nolock) on l.Leg_Key = m.Leg_Key and l.Status_Description = m.Status_Description and l.Move_Create_Timestamp = m. FirstMoveTime 
    --if you youse the filter then the case is useless?
    where m.Status_Description in ('DPKL') 
    group by m.Leg_Key
    ) mx on m.Leg_Key = lm.leg_key
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use aggregates directly with an `UPDATE`, since you are smashing rows together for the aggregation and a way to link the original row is not clear for the engine.

Calculate your aggregates in a subquery or CTE, then join against your table to update by your key:

```
;WITH AggregatedData AS
(
    SELECT
        -- I'm assuming these columns are your key on LegMove table
        m.Leg_Key, 
        l.Shipment_Number, 
        l.Shipment_Leg_Sequence,

        -- Aggregated values to udpate
        Event_Code = max(case when m.Status_Description = 'DPKL' then l.Status_Description else NULL end),                                                  
        Create_Date = max(case when m.Status_Description = 'DPKL' then dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,l.Move_Create_Timestamp),0) else NULL end), 
        PTimeStamp = max(case when m.Status_Description = 'DPKL' then l.Move_Create_Timestamp else NULL end), 
        Acrual_Date = max(case when m.Status_Description = 'DPKL' then dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,l.Move_Status_Timestamp),0) else NULL end) 
    FROM 
        wrkLegMove m 
        inner join MovementMaster l with(nolock) on 
            l.Leg_Key = m.Leg_Key and 
            l.Status_Description = m.Status_Description and 
            l.Move_Create_Timestamp = m. FirstMoveTime 
    where 
        m.Status_Description in ('DPKL') 
    group by 
        m.Leg_Key, 
        l.Shipment_Number, 
        l.Shipment_Leg_Sequence

)
UPDATE L SET
    Event_Code = A.Event_Code,
    Create_Date = A.Create_Date, 
    PTimeStamp = A.PTimeStamp,
    Acrual_Date = A.Acrual_Date
FROM
    LegMove AS L
    INNER JOIN AggregatedData AS A ON
        L.Leg_Key = A.Leg_Key AND
        L.Shipment_Number = A.Shipment_Number AND
        L.Shipment_Leg_Sequence = A.Shipment_Leg_Sequence
```

Beware that **if you join on less columns than the one you are aggregating, the updated values won't be consistent** as you will be creating a 1 to N relationship to the values to update and SQL Server will freely decide whichever to update.

Comment: Thanks for the solution :)